# Commands not found in Terminal except echo

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

In my terminal basic commands are not found like:

```
mds-macbook-pro:~ ZILLURRAHMAN$ ls
-bash: ls: command not found
mds-macbook-pro:~ ZILLURRAHMAN$ env
-bash: env: command not found
mds-macbook-pro:~ ZILLURRAHMAN$ edit
-bash: edit: command not found
mds-macbook-pro:~ ZILLURRAHMAN$ open
-bash: open: command not found
mds-macbook-pro:~ ZILLURRAHMAN$ vi
-bash: vi: command not found
mds-macbook-pro:~ ZILLURRAHMAN$ tail
-bash: tail: command not found
mds-macbook-pro:~ ZILLURRAHMAN$ ls
-bash: ls: command not found
```

But echo is working. Like: `mds-macbook-pro:~ ZILLURRAHMAN$ echo $PATH
“users/ZILLURRAHMAN/desktop/bioinformatics/bow-tie/bowtie2-2.2.3/BT2_HOME:??`

I can call up programs like `pico` using their full path like `/usr/bin/pico`.

Comment: The pico is another question. Stack Exchange works with only one question in each question

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your PATH is messed up. The reason why echo works is because it is a builtin command in the shell so the shell does not use your path to find the executable.

You need to see what script file had an `export PATH` in it which set it to `“users/ZILLURRAHMAN/desktop/bioinformatics/bow-tie/bowtie2-2.2.3/BT2_HOME:??` which has many error in it.

The usual files are ~/.profile ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile for more see many question on bash